# Ruby - Dynamically named variable based on a string read from a .csv

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a .csv from which I read and parse to create an instance of a class, I want to name the class after the string of text returned from the first row in the .csv.
I can create the classes just fine manually but want to read row[0] and name the variable after that.

eg.

```
CSV.foreach("banks.csv", :headers => true) do |row|

    ***contents of row[0]*** = Bank.new(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4])
```

row[0] == "Bank_of_America" for example, so I want the code to be equivalent to the following;

```
    Bank_of_America = Bank.new(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4])
```

I have read a few other replies on similar topics using instance_variable_set but cannot get the code given to work.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

edit: The following worked;

```
instance_variable_set("@#{row[0]}", Bank.new(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]))
```

Comment: May I ask why you want to set each `Bank` as a variable? Have you considering instead creating a hash and storing all the `Bank`s in that? How are you going to reference those Bank instances elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, another .csv refers to banks by name, so "Bank_of_America" the string will be .eval 'd to recognise the existing bank instance I want to create here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this and create an instance variable dynamically:

```
x = 10
 # => 10
instance_variable_set("@the_number_#{x}", x)
 # => 10
@the_number_10
 # => 10
```

You can replace `"@the_number_#{x}"` with `row[0]` now.

**EDIT:** Sorry, I didn't read the last part of you question about instance variables. So, how do you mean you can't get them to work? Does it come up with some kind of exception or just doesn't set to the right value. Give us the code that doesn't work.

Comment: 'Bank_of_America' is not allowed as an instance variable name (Name Error)

Sorry, tried pasting the code and can't get the code block format to work.

Comment: That is because you need to put a `@` sign in front of the variable you're trying to define like in my example (it is easy to miss). So you'd write something like `instance_variable_set("@#{row[0]}", x)`. *Are you familiar with string interpolation?*

Comment: Sorry not very, I looked it up there to clarify for myself. The code is now creating instances of the class but not named after the contents of row[0], at least not in a way I can refer to them by name, I can print them if I do a ObjectSpace.each_object(Bank) which shows they exist at least. I will have to try to find a way to see what is happening to them or what they are being named as I can't print them. Thanks for your help so far, I am further along than I was.

Comment: It was a scope problem, it seems to be working otherwise, I can continue from here, thanks very much Rafal. Unfortunately my rep is too low to give you a +1 sorry!

Comment: No problem @sam, glad to be a help!